# TextField that only works from some keys, including tab and enter in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `TextField` that i want to restrict it to a few keys, and if a click on that key it puts a specific value on the `TextField`, but i still want the `tab` and `enter` keys to work, if i click on any of these 2 keys the focus should go to the next control.

The code for that restrict `TextField` is:

```
                    TextField {
                    height: 479.9
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.rightMargin: 10
                    maximumLength: 5
                    Keys.onPressed: {
                        var c
                        switch (event.key) {
                        case Qt.Key_Up:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25B2)
                            break
                        case Qt.Key_Down:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25BC)
                            break
                        case Qt.Key_Right:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25B6)
                            break
                        default:
                            event.accepted = true
                            break
                        }
                        if (!event.accepted) {
                            var s = text.concat(c)
                            text = s.substr(Math.max(0,s.length-maximumLength), maximumLength)
                            event.accepted = true
                        }
                    }
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                }
```

A full working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 1400

    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int responsiveWidth: 1000
        property int maximumWidth: 900

        ScrollView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            function scrollToY(y) { //TODO: Não funciona com import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
                configScroll.flickableItem.contentY = y-30
            }
            GridLayout {
                columns: 2
                Keys.onPressed: {
                    if(event.key==Qt.Key_Return)
                    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i)
                        if (children[i].focus) {
                            children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
                            break
                        }
                }
                width: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? page.maximumWidth : page.width
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? (page.width - childrenRect.width)/2 : 10
                anchors.rightMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? 0 : 10


                    Label {
                        text: "Company Name"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }


                    Label {
                        text: "test"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField {
                        height: 479.9
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        maximumLength: 5
                        Keys.onPressed: {
                            var c
                            switch (event.key) {
                        case Qt.Key_Up:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25B2)
                            break
                        case Qt.Key_Down:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25BC)
                            break
                        case Qt.Key_Right:
                            c = String.fromCharCode(0x25B6)
                            break

                            default:
                                event.accepted = true
                                break
                            }
                            if (!event.accepted) {
                                var s = text.concat(c)
                                text = s.substr(Math.max(0,s.length-maximumLength), maximumLength)
                                event.accepted = true
                            }
                        }
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }
                    Label {
                        text: "label"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what changes i need to do on that `TextField`to have the `tab` and `enter` working again?

Comment: Maybe [TextInput.validator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#validator-prop) will fit your needs much better?

Comment: @folibis can you provide a simple example on how to do that? i think that would need a ```RegExpValidator```, but will there be a way to convert a for example ```Qt.Key_Up``` to another thing?